# 406 error with Stats Canada REST server and JSON using R API via RStudio

Tags: r, json, rest, api, post

The following code results in a 406 error. I get the correct results back from the server if I used Postman. I am submitting it from RStudio. I've included extensive header information in another version but it seems to make little difference. Information on Stats Canada's web service can be found here:

https://www.statcan.gc.ca/eng/developers/wds

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

statsmeta <- POST("https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/wds/rest/getCubeMetadata",
                  add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json"),
                  body = '{"query": [{"productId":35100003}]}')

print(head(statsmeta))
print(statsmeta)
```

Here are the contents of `statsmeta` which contains the response. I have posted both the output of `head` and of `print`:

head(statsmeta):

```
[1] "head of statsmeta"
$`url`
[1] "https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/wds/rest/getCubeMetadata"

$status_code
[1] 406

$headers
$`date`
[1] "Tue, 07 Aug 2018 23:00:14 GMT"

$`content-type`
[1] "application/json"

$connection
[1] "keep-alive"

$`x-content-type-options`
[1] "nosniff"

$`x-xss-protection`
[1] "1; mode=block"

$`content-security-policy`
[1] "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.statcan.gc.ca *.demdex.net *.omtrdc.net *.everesttech.net blob:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.statcan.gc.ca blob:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.statcan.gc.ca *.googletagmanager.com *.adobedtm.com *.jsdelivr.net *.mathjax.org cdnjs.cloudflare.com blob:; connect-src 'self' *.statcan.gc.ca *.demdex.net *.omtrdc.net; img-src 'self' *.statcan.gc.ca *.demdex.net *.omtrdc.net *.everesttech.net *.jsdelivr.net data:; font-src 'self' *.statcan.gc.ca; worker-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.statcan.gc.ca blob:;"

$`strict-transport-security`
[1] "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"

$`set-cookie`
[1] "TS011c6724=01bc1e933993d7b7bff936018fb1f806eaaa6dec0dbabad490dc535fa611694ebed67d8046; Path=/"

$`transfer-encoding`
[1] "chunked"

attr(,"class")
[1] "insensitive" "list"       

$all_headers
$all_headers[[1]]
$all_headers[[1]]$`status`
[1] 406

$all_headers[[1]]$version
[1] "HTTP/1.1"

$all_headers[[1]]$headers
$`date`
[1] "Tue, 07 Aug 2018 23:00:14 GMT"

$`content-type`
[1] "application/json"

$connection
[1] "keep-alive"

$`x-content-type-options`
[1] "nosniff"

$`x-xss-protection`
[1] "1; mode=block"

$`content-security-policy`
[1] "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.statcan.gc.ca *.demdex.net *.omtrdc.net *.everesttech.net blob:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.statcan.gc.ca blob:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.statcan.gc.ca *.googletagmanager.com *.adobedtm.com *.jsdelivr.net *.mathjax.org cdnjs.cloudflare.com blob:; connect-src 'self' *.statcan.gc.ca *.demdex.net *.omtrdc.net; img-src 'self' *.statcan.gc.ca *.demdex.net *.omtrdc.net *.everesttech.net *.jsdelivr.net data:; font-src 'self' *.statcan.gc.ca; worker-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.statcan.gc.ca blob:;"

$`strict-transport-security`
[1] "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"

$`set-cookie`
[1] "TS011c6724=01bc1e933993d7b7bff936018fb1f806eaaa6dec0dbabad490dc535fa611694ebed67d8046; Path=/"

$`transfer-encoding`
[1] "chunked"

attr(,"class")
[1] "insensitive" "list"       



$cookies
                domain  flag path secure expiration       name
1 www150.statcan.gc.ca FALSE    /  FALSE       <NA> TS011c6724
                                                                       value
1 01bc1e933993d7b7bff936018fb1f806eaaa6dec0dbabad490dc535fa611694ebed67d8046

$content
 [1] 7b 22 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65 22 3a 22 4a 53 4f 4e 20 73 79 6e 74 61 78 20 65 72 72 6f 72
[30] 2c 20 70 6c 65 61 73 65 20 72 65 66 65 72 20 74 6f 20 74 68 65 20 6d 61 6e 75 61 6c 20
[59] 74 6f 20 63 68 65 63 6b 20 74 68 65 20 69 6e 70 75 74 20 4a 53 4f 4e 20 63 6f 6e 74 65
[88] 6e 74 22 7d
```

Statsmeta:

```
Response [https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/wds/rest/getCubeMetadata]
  Date: 2018-08-07 23:00
  Status: 406
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 91 B
```

Comment: it's a 406 error https://httpstatuses.com/406 that info may help you sort it out

Comment: are you able to replicate the POST on a web browser?

Comment: Hello sckott. Thanks - I recognize that the 406 error seems to indicate that the the response type the server  is returning is not compatible with the Accept HTTP header in my request. Even if I set wild cards for that, e.g.*/*  it won't accept it.

Comment: Hello chinsoon. Thanks for your question. I tried the Postman extension for Chrome and that worked. However, I can't make it work from RStudio.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but the [`get_cansim_cube_metadata`](https://mountainmath.github.io/cansim/reference/get_cansim_cube_metadata.html) [cansim package](https://mountainmath.github.io/cansim/index.html) might fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Trying with Chrome's Postman extension, I found this way that can work in RStudio:

```
POST(url = url,  # get changed tables info
     body = '[{"productId":35100003}]',
     encode = "raw", verbose(),
     add_headers(.headers = c("Content-Type"="application/json"))))

-> CONNECT www150.statcan.gc.ca:443 HTTP/1.1
-> Host: www150.statcan.gc.ca:443
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.59.0 r-curl/3.2 httr/1.3.1
-> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
<- 
-> POST /t1/wds/rest/getCubeMetadata HTTP/1.1
-> Host: www150.statcan.gc.ca
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.59.0 r-curl/3.2 httr/1.3.1
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Cookie: TS011c6724=01bc1e9339dc3498d6f1a974c756f1d3f9f555aa0f53e9eda2776efdac2db1d620299319c9
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Type: application/json
-> Content-Length: 24
-> 
>> [{"productId":35100003}]

<- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<- Date: Fri, 11 Jan 2019 16:49:10 GMT
<- Content-Type: application/json
<- Connection: keep-alive
<- Vary: Accept-Encoding
<- Expires: Fri, 11 Jan 2019 16:51:10 GMT
<- Cache-Control: max-age=120
<- X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
<- X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
<- Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.statcan.gc.ca *.statcan.ca *.demdex.net *.omtrdc.net *.everesttech.net blob:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *.statcan.gc.ca blob:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.statcan.gc.ca *.googletagmanager.com *.adobedtm.com *.jsdelivr.net *.mathjax.org cdnjs.cloudflare.com blob:; connect-src 'self' *.statcan.gc.ca *.demdex.net *.omtrdc.net; img-src 'self' *.statcan.gc.ca *.demdex.net *.omtrdc.net *.everesttech.net *.jsdelivr.net data:; font-src 'self' *.statcan.gc.ca; worker-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.statcan.gc.ca blob:;
<- X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
<- Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
<- X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
<- X-Proxy-Cache: MISS
<- Cache-Control: public
<- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
<- Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
<- Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range
<- Access-Control-Expose-Headers: DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range
<- Content-Encoding: gzip
<- Set-Cookie: TS011c6724=01bc1e9339dc3498d6f1a974c756f1d3f9f555aa0f53e9eda2776efdac2db1d620299319c9; Path=/
<- Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```